# Populating drop-down list with PHP not working

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to get a drop-down list populated with PHP to my website but it is not displaying anything. It's empty [as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpkIi.png). Under the state it shows nothing.

Please help me to get some details from my database results.

My code is:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost', '', '')or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db('')or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
?>

<form>
    <div class="form-group">        
        <div class="form-control-small">
            <select id="search_status" name="state" data-placeholder="State">
                <option value=""> </option>
                <?php
                    $dd_res=mysql_query("Select DISTINCT state from MyTable");
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($dd_res))
                    { 
                        echo "<option value='$row[state]'> $row[state] </option>";
                    }
                ?>          
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-control-small">
            <select id="search_bedrooms" name="dist" data-placeholder="District">
                <option value=""> </option>
                    <?php
                        $dd_res=mysql_query("Select DISTINCT dist from MyTable");
                        while($r=mysql_fetch_row($dd_res))
                        { 
                            echo "<option value='$row[dist]'> $row[dist] </option>";
                        }
                    ?>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fullcolor">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this:

```
$arr = array(1 => 'MP', 2 => 'UP');

echo '<select>';
foreach($arr as $key => $val)
{
    echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$val.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

It will generate html like:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">MP</option>
  <option value="2">UP</option>
</select>
```

Comment: no i have to extract the details from my database tabale.

Comment: Its just an example, replace the array with the database extracted value array

Answer (score 0):

You cant display Array values in a string, even with double quotes.

Either you have to use curly brackets or concatenation

```
echo "<option value='{$row[state]}'> {$row[state]} </option>";
```

or

```
echo "<option value='".$row[state]."'> ".$row[state]." </option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 echo "<option value='".$row['state']."'> ".$row['state']."</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the `mysql_fetch_row()` fetches one row of data from the result associated with the specified result identifier. The row is returned as an array. Each result column is stored in an array offset, starting at offset 0.

This means that you cannot reach your column names like this: $row["state"].

Try instead:

`echo "<option value='$row[0]'> $row[0] </option>";`

However the *mysql_query* and *mysql_fetch_row* function are deprecated, and they will be removed in PHP version 7. It can be an issue for you too. Consider upgrading to something more modern way of interacting with MySQL.
You will find alternatives here:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: it doesn't give any change.